# Python: Stop script execution without closing the program

Tags: python-2.7, enterprise-architect

I wrote an Addin for Enterprise Architect, and now I am working on Erfror-Handling. When an error is found I am using the sys.exit() function to stop the script, but after that, another error from Enterprise Architect is raised saying: "Exception while attempting to comunicate with Addin".
I guess that must has something to do with the fact that sys.exit() closes python and does not abort only the script execution.
I only want to pop up my errors.
Any ideas how to overcome this?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can't you just throw an exception from within your script? Then potentially catch it and relay it to Enterprise architect somehow (how does it communicate with the add-in?)?

Comment: here is an architecture of how the interaction works:
https://geertbellekens.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/ea-addin.png

Comment: Have you tried `exit()` rather than `sys.exit()`?

Comment: Yeah, these commands seem all to stop the program. Meanwhile I am writing a Logfile.txt that collects all errors in a text document at the end of the program.